# How to Display data in table format in Shoes

Tags: ruby, shoes

Is there any way to display data in table format in Shoes?

```
    <table border ="1">
      <tr>
       <th>Name</th>
       <th> Content</th>
      </tr>
      @products.each do |product|
        <tr>
         <td> product.name </td>
         <td>product.detail</td>
        </tr>
      end
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shoes does not have a native table construct (yet). There is an open issue on shoes4 about adding one but don't expect that soon or count on it being implemented.

You can mix flows with fixed width values to achieve a table like effect. E.g. put some flows with a fixed width next to each other and put these in a stack. I made a table like construct [here](https://github.com/PragTob/pomodoro_tracker/blob/master/lib/pomodoro_tracker/slots/activity_table_slot.rb)